# php an array of reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have two arrays. one will be added with arrays as children, another one keeps references to the array being added to the first one.

```
$list=array();
$stack=array();
```

in a for loop:

```
$list[]=array('something');
$stack[]=& end($list); //errors: Only variables should be assigned by reference
```

what am i doing wrong here? thanks for help.

Comment: The error message seems pretty self-explanatory. And why the `new Array`? Just `Array` will do.

Comment: @tomalak, sorry, that was a mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

```
$stack[] = &$list[count($list)-1];  //> Assuming numeric index incremental
```

or

```
end($list);
$stack[] = &$list[key($list)];
```

Comment: this way, the reference is to $var, not to end($list) ?? right?? I want the reference to the end($list), so it will not disppare outside the for loop.

Comment: `&=` means something different. Probably not what's intended.

Comment: Still it won't be a reference to the last element of $list but to the new variable $var.

Comment: @Gedrox Taken from the documentation: "The same syntax can be used with functions that return references, and with the new operator".

Comment: The problem is that in the first line the reference is lost. The function "end" returns the copy of the last element from the array.

Comment: @duskwuff: what's `&=` stands for?

Comment: @yes123: `&=` is a compound assignment operator -- similar to `+=`, but with `&` (bitwise AND).

Comment: @duskwuff okok i thought that but considering there isn't any reference on php docu i was in doubt with the reference

Answer (score 0):

Objects will be always passed by reference in PHP 5.

**EDITED**

But if array is not a class then

```
$element = array();
$list[] = &$element;
$stack[] = &$element;
```

Comment: sorry, I am a beginner in php. so does the same to arrays??

Comment: The code is ment if you work with PHP arrays. Of course you need to pass filled array into the $element.

Comment: so both list and stack are arrays of reference to $element??